# Ubuntu 16.04 slow performance on notebook

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, performance

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my notebook (Intel Core i3-350M, 4GB DDR3, Intel HD) and in comparison to my old 12.04 installation, it's extremely slow. Even opening the terminal takes several seconds.

So my question: what are my options, what do you guys suggest? It's worth installing 14.04 in this case, or another (ie. more lightweight) distro?

I tried Ubuntu Mate but didn't like very much, I really miss the integration of menu bar with the title bar of Unity interface.

Comment: What's the CPU usage at idle in 14.04?

Comment: @Android Dev, I don't really know, because I didn't installed it in the first place. I had Ubuntu 12.04 and went straight to a fresh install of 16.04. I'm really surprised of how awful 16.04 is running in there, wasn't expecting for that, dunno if I missed something.

Comment: I see no problem using Ubuntu 14.04 with an older kernel < 4. I don't know much about 3.19 but 3.13 was good for me. I do like 16.04 improvements and think you should spend a little research and time making it work. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Kernel 4.4 and I immediately hopped up to 4.6.3 and then 4.7.3. There's no horsepower reason why your processor shouldn't work once you figure out the Ubuntu 16.04 or Kernel 4.4 glitches and correct them IMO.

Comment: @AndroidDev I think you meant 16.04?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, if he meant 16.04, I unfortunately don't remember. I installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 shortly after and although it improved a little, I really miss the Unity interface. You said that this performance is not normal, do you have any tips of what should I do? Could it be missing drivers? Do the automatic upgrade of Ubuntu install all the missing drivers? I'm willing to try 16.04 again.

Comment: @victorbrt, I meant AndroidDev meant to say 16.04 instead of 14.04, just like you said. If you wanted 16.04 Xubuntu or Lubuntu could be considerations but I would go with 14.04 until the 16.04 glitches are worked out. It's not Ubuntu to blame but more Kernel > 4 and Intel microprocessor code. Unfortunately I don't know anything about your circa 2010 i-3 Processor. You can go check out my answer about intel and kernel  at [http://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown/828027#828027] but I'm not sure how much it will help.

Comment: @victorbrt I should add I have a 2007 laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo 2 Ghz and it runs Ubuntu 14.04 very nicely wit 4 GB ram. I haven't tried it with 16.04 yet because I have a 2012 laptop with Intel i-7 Core I'm using all the time with 16.04 learning about new features and overcoming glitches. You should have zero problems running 14.04 and the interface is almost identical to 16.04. I don't know the 12.04 interface so can't say what changes you'll experience.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, well, seems like 16.04 is a little unstable to be called LTS, heh? I don't like the idea of installing an old version (just OCD things) but... if there's nothing I can do to improve this situation on 16.04 I think the 14.04 will be my best choice. IIRC, Ubuntu 12.04 is very similiar to 14.04/16.04: it already comes with Unity interface.

Comment: You could simply try a lighter Desktop environment like XFCE - just install the additional package (as in: `sudo apt-get install xfce4`) - logout and see if it feels better.

Comment: No, I really meant 14.04.

Comment: @dufte, when 16.04 was installed, I tried to use the gnome session flashback in "Metacity" mode and the performance was the same. The apps were slow to start up (even terminal itself) and the boot time was awful too.